# jQuery Unable to attach event handler to <form> created by .load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

first time question...
This link on my page

```
<a onclick="$('#mainbody').load('pages/login.php', tester());">Login</a>
```

generates this form

```
<form id="form">
    <b>Email Address:</b> <input type="email" name="usrEmail" placeholder="email address" required><br />
    <b>Password:</b> <input type="password" name="usrPass" placeholder="password" required><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Log in">
</form>
```

my .js contains this;

```
function tester(){
    $("#form").submit(function() {
        alert('Handler called.');
        return false;
    }); 
}
```

...and nothing happens when the form is submitted.
However, if I change the link to

```
<a onclick="$('#mainbody').load('pages/login.php', function(){$( '#form' ).submit(function() { alert('Handler called.'); return false;});});">Login</a>
```

...this works perfectly.
Functionally I can't see any difference between calling a named function or defining in the callback itself, but obviously the browser can!
What am I doing wrong? Is it syntax? Timing?
Or - and I'm still finding my way with jQuery - is it because even though I'm calling an eventhandler that references #form AFTER it exists, the fact the function was created first ignores it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it because even though I'm calling an eventhandler that references #form AFTER it exists

Yes. You should look into the jQuery delegate method.

If you say

```
$("body").delegate("form","submit",function(){
    alert("handeled");
});
```

It will work after its been loaded from a different source.

Comment: Not enough rep, apparently!

Answer (score 4):

You are binding the result of a call to the `tester` function as the callback to `.load` (which is nothing).  Do this instead:

```
$("#mainbody").load('pages/login.php', tester);
```

That is, use the function *name* as the callback.

Comment: I am having one of those days!

Answer (score 0):

Since the form element is not in the initial DOM you need to

- Reattach it on callback , call your function on load callback
- or Make it respond to those change

  $("#form").die('submit').live('submit',function() {
      alert('Handler called.');
      return false;
  });

Note that I removed the function